# when does a thread wake up from condition.wait()

Tags: c++, multithreading

I wanted to know when does a thread wake up from a condition
I have something like this on the consumer thread

```
while(true)
                {
                    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> guard(mmutex);
                    cv.wait(guard, [this]{ return this->checkcondition(); } ); //sleeps when does this wake up
                    if(vector.size()>0) 
                    {
                       ....
                    }
                }
```

This is the producer thread

```
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(mmutex);
vector.push_back(s);
cv.notify_one();
```

Now my question is in the statement

```
cv.wait(guard, [this]{ return this->checkcondition(); } );
```

if checkcondition() returns false causing .wait to sleep(block).
When does .wait check the predicate again ??

Comment: When the thread wakes up. This is to avoid spurious wakeups.

Comment: and the wakeup is done by condition.notify_one(); ?

Comment: Yes, but there are also "spurious wakeups". When the event is signalled, something *might* have changed, so the lambda callback is invoked to check if it should proceed or go back to sleep.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++11 30.5.1 "Class condition_variable" explains the behavior you can count on. There are 3 things that will unblock a thread blocked inside a `condition_variable::wait()` call. The function will unblock:

- when signaled by a call to `notify_one()`
- when signaled by a call to `notify_all()`
- spuriously

In a `wait()` call that takes a predicate, the compiler generates code that acts like:

```
while (!pred())
    wait(lock);
```

So if the predicate returns `false` (or equivalent), the `wait()` will be called again.  It will not unblock again until one of those three things mentioned before occurs again.

Usually the predicate should "match" the event that caused `notify_one()` or `notify_all()` to be called.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `cv.notify_one`, the waiting thread (*one* of the waiting threads, if there are more than one) will wake up.

The thread that just woke up will then lock the mutex and call `this->checkcondition()`. If that returns true, it will return from `wait`. Otherwise, it will unlock the mutex again and go back to sleep.